# How to apply a filter to new tabs

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Hi everybody, in case I would like to apply a measure in these new tabs  in order that only where a filter is selected it should show values while if not the symbol to visualize the symbol is --, what should text in measure? I specify that % values that you see in the pic are actegorical

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HASONEVALUE('table'[column]`) to determine there is only one value (ie filtered to one value).

```
Col B % = 
  IF(
    HASONEVALUE('YourTable'[Country]),
    MIN('YourTable'[Col B]),
    "--"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying this actually it would be bettere to have something more specific since I tried so long to add measure as tooltip in new cards but it didn't work. The major filter contain country name, so basically percentage in new cards should be observed if the country name is selected, otherwise the symbol that should appear is --.

Comment: Sorry, is there an ask/question? If so, share a link to a sample PBIX.

Comment: The table with three columns of %, is there a fourth column for Country? So a row for each country?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That is the way.

Comment: Updated the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you enter this measure?

Comment: ? What do you mean?